# How to remove duplicates using Java 8 streams based on criteria

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a `List` of objects and I want to remove the duplicates based on criteria: compare the `descr` value, if at least one `row` has `Invalid` as `descr`'s value, use that object and remove the rest of the objects with the same `row` value.

```
class Sample {
  public String row;
  public String descr;
}
```

Sample input data:

```
[{"01", "Invalid"}, {"01", "One more"}, {"02", "Invalid"}, {"03", "another test"}]
```

Result should be:

```
[{"01", "Invalid"}, {"02", "Invalid"}, {"03", "another test"}]
```

Comment: What if there are no "Invalid"s in a row#, do you keep them all? Also do you have to use streams? Also is your example code even written in Java?

Comment: yes, keep the rest of them . Good to use streams if possible. Yes I am using Java.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that this is a duplicate of "Java 8 Distinct by Property"

Comment: Sorry, but this description makes no sense at all: “if at least one `row` has `Invalid` as `descr`'s value”.

Answer (score 4):

## `Set`

A [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) in Java is a collection of objects without duplicates.

The idea would be :

- Storing in a `Set` the `row` values of the objects where `desc` equals to `"Invalid"`.
- Applying `removeIf()` on the initial list to remove elements that have row values contained in the `Set` but with `descr` not equals to `"Invalid"`.

Such as :

```
List<Foo> foos = ...;

Set<String> invalidRows = 
foos.stream()
    .filter(f->f.getDescr().equals("Invalid"))
    .map(Foo::getRow)
    .collect(toSet());

foos.removeIf(f-> invalidRows.contains(f.getRow()) && !f.getDescr().equals("Invalid"))
```